# How to generate a color based on an alphanumeric string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, colors, hex

I want something like "hey there" to turn into, for example, `#316583`.

I want a string of any length to be "boiled down" so to speak to a hex color. I'm at loss even where to start.

I was thinking, an MD5 hash of every string is different - but how to turn that hash into a hex color number?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can just take a few first digits:

```
require 'digest/md5'
color = Digest::MD5.hexdigest('My text')[0..5]
```

Comment: I'd write a (slightly) more declarative `Digest::MD5.hexdigest('My text')[0, 6]` but other than that, +1.

Answer (score 3):

You can mod the md5 value by 2^24 and print that result in hex with a # sign before it.

Here's a bad way without the MD5, that gives very low values on short strings, but shows the idea:

```
sprintf("#%06x", ("asdf".sum % (256*256*256)))
```

output:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :032 > sprintf("#%06x", ("asdf".sum % (256*256*256)))
 => "#00019e"
```

Replace `"asdf".each_byte.inject(:+)` with the MD5 value and you should be good!

Comment: String has a `sum` method which may be more useful than `.each_byte.inject(:+)`.

Comment: just double checked (trust but verify) and yes, this is better.  Updating answer.